# log out confirmation box in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php code for logout page but i need to have a confirmation box pop-up first if i click the navigation box to logout...if  I want to logout or not...can any1 help me?? please

code:

```
<?php
include("connection.php");


// Delete certain session
unset($_SESSION['username']);
// Delete all session variables
// session_destroy();
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
    $stat="UPDATE users SET status='logout'";
        mysql_query($stat); 
// Jump to login page
header('Location: index.php');


?>
```

Comment: if (confirm("Are you sure?")) { /* do work */ }

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions?

Comment: @Mike, gone but not forgotten. Many of us are still on 5.3- meaning their not yet gone methods. I like em better than the new stuff anyway, myself.

Comment: @SpYk3HH they're not "gone" in any version yet. They are still in 5.5, just deprecated and will produce a warning if `E_DEPRECATED` is enabled, and rightfully so. You probably like them because you're used to them, but mysqli is practically no different in its usage. PHP devs didn't just get together one day and say up "hey, let's deprecate stuff". They are deprecated for a reason.

Comment: @Mike Oh I know the new is better, and I'll adjust eventually. Let's just say my first attempt at molling over a whole site with the `i` upgrade did not go well, and "no", they don't function just like the old.

Comment: @SpYk3HH I was recently in the same position and overhauled one of my larger programs to PDO, but I definitely prefer it over ext/mysql. The added security of prepared statements makes me feel all warm inside. Like a roaring fireplace on a cold winter's night... or something.

Comment: @Mike that may have been my prob. I have my own personally written class for security and escaping and such. Gonna have to upgrade ... bleh

Comment: Anyway... I think a logout confirmation is annoying. I would advise against it.

Answer (score 3):

maybe this is what you are trying to achieve?

```
var logout = confirm("Are you sure to logout?");

if(logout){
     location.href = "pathtologout.php";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Most simple:

```
<a href="logout.php" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to logout?');">Logout</a>
```

Comment: `onclick` inline is so '90's! :-P

Comment: @SpYk3HH Just provide a solution, don't think too much or you may say `mysql_query` is so '90's! too :)

Comment: Sometimes it's something so simple that it doesn't require a lot of code.
Doesn't matter if it's 90's or 2010's... If it's not deprecated and will not be for next 4 decades why not use it, enjoy it and get on with the rest of the day... I Love xdazz answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a simple confirmation, you can do this

```
$('#logout').click(function(){
    var reallyLogout=confirm("Do you really want to log out?");
    if(reallyLogout){
        location.href="path/to/logout/file.php";
    }
});
```

If you can't use jQuery(!), you can use pure Javascript to attach the event handler

```
function logout(){
        var reallyLogout=confirm("Do you really want to log out?");
        if(reallyLogout){
            location.href="path/to/logout/file.php";
        }
}
var el = document.getElementById("logout");
if (el.addEventListener) {
        el.addEventListener("click", logoutfunction, false);
    } else {
        el.attachEvent('onclick', logoutfunction);
}
```

Comment: requires jQuery. I think he's looking at simple JS atm.

Comment: @SpYk3HH but jquery is great and does all the things! :(

Comment: I couldn't agree with you more. But based on the "speech" of the question, I don't think this OP is even yet aware of jQuery. Looks like he is just learning PHP an JS.